# How to get parent element form iframe about html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get parent element form other html's  iframe?

i have a parent html file, and it call other html to be it's iframe as following:

`index.html:`

```
<iframe  id ="MainPage"  src="aa.html" style="overflow:auto"></frame>
<div id ="mainDiv"> abc </div>
```

Then in the aa.html file, i want to get the parents element in the aa.html

`aa.html:`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maindiv = window.parent.document.getElementById('mainDiv');
maindiv.height(300);
});
```

But it doesn't work at all when i open the index.html file... 
what wrong with my code?

Comment: You haven't closed your `<iframe>` tag. That might be a reason.

Comment: Thanks your opinion, in my code, i have close it. I just forget to copy :).

Comment: Did you include jQuery in `aa.html`? Try using Developer Tools (F12 sometimes works) or a javascript debugger, and view the `Console` tab to see what is going on. It should point you to the offending code.

Comment: As a plain JS works in my browser:
`var maindiv = window.parent.document.getElementById('mainDiv');
maindiv.style.height = "300px";`
Also keep in mind that, if you are testing this as local files in Chrome, it will have security issues. I've checked in IE and it worked.

Comment: Finally, i have check it. if i run on IE9, it works.
but if i run it on Chrome 36.0.1985.125, it fails
So how can i fixed it in Chrome?
Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var $mainDiv = window.parent.$('#mainDiv');
    $mainDiv.height(300);
});
```

You also want to fix your HTML by closing the IFRAME tag:

`<iframe  id ="MainPage"  src="aa.html" style="overflow:auto"></iframe>`

Comment: Why would you think, that OP wants to resize the iframe, not the DIV?

Comment: it looked like a typo before he included the closing tag

Comment: .....Thanks your opinion.
But why "$(window.parent.document).find('#MainPage');" can't effect at all ....
Will this statement doesn't work between two html files?

Comment: I fixed it. I think it had to do with scoping the $ function. If you call it via `window.parent.$()` it should work.. updated example

Comment: Thanks, but I just forget to copy the closing tag. :) @nothingisnecessary